Evaluate $\int\tan(x)\tan(\tan (x))\mathrm dx$
I want to evaluate the integral
$$\int\tan(x)\tan(\tan x)\mathrm dx$$
Failed Attempt: Taking $\tan x=t$, the integral  becomes
$$\mathcal I=\int\frac{t\tan t}{1+t^2}\mathrm dt$$
Then, IBP:
$$\mathcal I=\frac12\tan(t)\ln(1+t^2)-\frac12\int\sec^2(t)\ln(1+t^2)\mathrm dt$$
This seems to have complicated the integral even more.
The anti-derivative seems to be a non-elementary function as per WolframAlpha.
Context:
Yesterday, on my math exam, one of the questions was to solve this homogeneous and exact ODE:
$$(x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx)y\sin\frac{y}{x}=(x\mathrm dy+y\mathrm dx)x\cos\frac{y}{x}$$
$\bigg{(}$This can be easily solved by recognizing $\mathrm d(xy)=x\mathrm dy+y\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx}{x^2}$ or by writing the expression for $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ and then taking $y=tx\implies\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=t+x\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}$.$\bigg{)}$
Later, I thought of a variation in this ODE:
$$(x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx)y\sin\frac{y}{x}=(x\mathrm dx+y\mathrm dy)x\cos\frac{y}{x}$$
Using $\mathrm d\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{x\mathrm dy-y\mathrm dx}{x^2+y^2}$, the ODE becomes
$$\frac{y}{x}\tan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)d\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac12\mathrm d\left(\ln(x^2+y^2)\right)$$
The LHS of the above ODE led me to think of the aforesaid integral.

Interested to see as well!

Please explain the downvote. I have added my attempt and context, what else is missing?

What do you need concretely: solve your differential equation or that integral?

@VadimChernetsov only the integral. If I know that, solving the ODE is a piece of cake.

In the starting, I've already mentioned that I want to evaluate the integral. The differential equation was just for context purposes.

One idea is to see if you can get a recursive formula after subsituting $\frac1{1+t^2}$ using the geometric series, but I don't think it will yield a closed form

@AmrutAyan what is the $\psi$? And how does one go about deriving this result?

@MathGuy its the digamma function, $B_n$ is the nth bernoulli number, overall a big mess but atleast it converges (miraculously), this above result is plain taylor series usage

@AmrutAyan. I think that the arguments of the digamma function are not correct. Isn't $$\psi\left(\frac{2 n+3}{4}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{2 n+1}{4}\right)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici, My bad, i think the correct evaluation to $4\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^{2n}(x),dx=\left[\psi\left(\frac{2n+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2n+1}{4}\right)\right]$, so that should make this, $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \tan(x)\tan(\tan(x)),dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2n}(1-4^n)(-4)^n}{4(2n)!}\left[\psi\left(\frac{2n+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2n+1}{4}\right)\right]$,...

@AmrutAyan. Who never forgot a term ? Not me. Cheers :-)

Using, as @AmrutAyan already did in comments, the Taylor series of $\tan(t)$, the problem is
$$\int\tan(x)\tan(\tan (x))\, dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n \left(1-4^n\right) B_{2 n}}{(2 n)!}\int \tan ^{2 n}(x)\,dx$$
$$\int \tan ^{2 n}(x)\,dx=\frac{\tan ^{2 n+1}(x)}{2 n+1} \, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2};n+\frac{3}{2};-\tan ^2(x)\right)$$ where appears the Gaussian hypergeomatric function.
Correcting a minor typo (if I am correct)
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \tan ^{2 n}(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi \left(\frac{2 n+3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{2 n+1}{4}\right)\right)$$
If $a_n$ is the summand, using the asymptotic formula of Bernoulli numbers
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\sim \frac{5}{2 \pi ^2} \left(1-\frac 1 n \right)+\frac{3 \coth (n \log (2))}{2 \pi ^2}\left(1-\frac 1 n \right)\to \frac{4}{\pi ^2}$$ which makes the convergence quite fast.
Computing the partial sums
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 1 & 0.214602 \\
 2 & 0.254179 \\
 3 & 0.265015 \\
 4 & 0.268339 \\
 5 & 0.269422 \\
 6 & 0.269788 \\
 7 & 0.269916 \\
 8 & 0.269961 \\
 9 & 0.269978 \\
 10 & 0.269984 \\
 11 & 0.269986 \\
 12 & 0.269987 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Edit
If, for the same range, we use (as you wrote)
$$I=\frac12\tan(t)\log(1+t^2)-\frac12\int\sec^2(t)\log(1+t^2)\,dt$$  Using
$$\sec^2(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{b_n}\, t^{2n}$$ where the $a_n$ and $b_n$ form sequences $A002430$ and $A117972$ in $OEIS$, we should have, as a result,
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \log (2) \tan (1)-\frac 12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{b_n}\,\frac{\log (2)-\Phi\left(-1,1,n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2 n+1}$$ where appears  the Lerch transcendent function.
Using $12$ terms as above, the value is $0.269991$.
It could be worth to notice that
$$\Phi\left(-1,1,n+\frac{3}{2}\right)=(-1)^n \left(2\frac{ a_{n}}{b_n}-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
where $a_n$ and $b_n$ correspond to sequences $A007509$ and  $A025547$ in $OEIS$ (with a shift of $1$).
